# Can fwrite() only be used for .txt files / Storing form data in another .PHP file possible?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to have form content saved, posted and stored in another .php file. The fwrite() function looks like it could have been of use, however from what I gather it can only write to .txts.

Of course, the other option would be to have the form content, saved posted, and stored in a database, then called on as needed, however I'm trying to figure a self-hosted solution for a script without the user needing to configure a database of their own.

If you've got any suggestions, they'd be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Since a PHP file is just text, you can use fwrite to write to it.

Comment: Why do you think that `fwrite()` can write only to .txt files? You do know file extension doesn't have anything to do with `fopen()` / `fwrite()`? Alternatively, check out `file_put_contents()` function at php.net.

Comment: A PHP installation without a database such as Mysql is a very rare occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty bad idea to save form output to a php file. What gives you the impression that fwrite is limited to .txt files? It isn't. I would recommend using a database like sqlite, or allowing developer to specify details for their own database. If it must be self hosted ( who on earth has a server running php without access to a db server?) then use two way encrypted text files, or store the files in a folder outside of your web root.

Comment: It wouldn't be that they have a server without access to databases, it would be that they couldn't set-up a database by themselves (as most of their hosting providers provide one click installs for most of the applications they'd use, e.g. Wordpress). That said, I'm sure a simple setup documentation should suffice.

Comment: Fair point! In that case, you could even have it use text files as default, and provide a simple doc to switch it to using a database via config setting, and supply necessary connection details :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a PHP file is a text file so it can be written to just like a '.txt' file.

It doesn't matter what the extension is.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression file extension mattered as all examples I saw of fopen()/fwrite() being written to .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely bad idea...

If a user posts the following content:

```
<?php exec("rm -rv *") ?>
```

then your server has had it, you should always set the mime type to plain text, and the extension to txt.

To answer your question, the file functions can write to nay file-type or encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can write everything you like with `fwrite()` including binary data. However, its *never* a good idea to let a user decide, what code may now, or later be executed.